# ACE with multiple app instances on same pc - only first gets the message

Tags: c++, udp, ace

I'm trying to create application where multiple instances will run on same machine and they will communicate together via UDP via the same port.

I was reading many threads on StackOverflow about it that it should be possible.

Though, when I open connection from each application instance I can see that each instance sends a message but only first instance (if first is closed then second...) receives that message.

I'm using ACE library for the communication. Excerpt from code:

```
ACE_SOCK_Dgram_Mcast dgram;
ACE_INET_Addr *listenAddress = new ACE_INET_Addr(12345, ACE_LOCALHOST);
dgram.open(*listenAddress);

ACE_INET_Addr peer_address;
char buffer[1024];

dgram.send(buffer, 256);

while (true)
{
    if (dgram.recv(buffer, 256, peer_address, 0, &receiveLoopTimeout) != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Received" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I also found out that if I call "dgram.join(*listenAddress)" then I get error, code ENODEV from the first instance of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do... send a message multicast so multiple receivers get it, or allow multiple processes to receive on the same UDP port unicast... I'm guessing the former.

You're using the ACE_SOCK_Dgram_Mcast class but with unicast addressing and operations. So only one instance will receive that message.

Check the ACE_wrappers/tests/Multicast_Test.cpp for examples of how to send and receive multicast.

Comment: Hello, well I'm trying to do both - send message so multiple receivers get it + allow multiple processes to receive on the same UDP port. For testing purposes I'm sending it only to local computer to test if it can be received by multiple processes. I will check that example, thanks.

Comment: Oh, so now when I use one dgram with (12345, "10.10.0.255") for sending and another with (12345, ACE_LOCALHOST) for reception then I get all the messages.